# Looping through a char array in AT&T assembly

Tags: assembly, intel, att

I have an assignment to write a simple version of sprintf in x86 AT&T assembler, taking in a string/char-array and an unsigned char, then printing the string as sprintf would (so a string containing "%d\n" and unsigned char '3' would print "3\n").

My idea is to read each byte and compare it to a '%' character, if it's not a '%' char, I add it to the register, and if it is, I do some other stuff to do the formatting (not gotten that far yet). But I'm a complete newbie at assembler programming, so how do I loop through the string?

I currently have:

```
loop1:
  movl %ebx, %edx   #Get string from address in %ebx
  cmpb $'%', %dl    #Compare with %
  je index_found    #If equal, go to index_found
  addb %dl, %al     #Else add byte to %eax
  incl %ecx         #increase counter by 1

  cmpb $0, %dl      #Check if end of string
  jz  print         #If end of string, go to print and return
```

I'm guessing my issue lies with the fact that I don't use the %ecx register for actually counting, but I don't know the syntax for it..

Comment: Your comment `#Else add byte to %eax` is wrong: if `addb %dl, %al` overflows, it won't carry into the rest of `%eax`.  You're adding only to AL, not the full EAX.  You need to zero or sign-extend a byte first before adding to a 32-bit register.

Comment: But anyway, the real problem is that none of the instructions in the loop load from memory.  Did you mean `movzbl (%ebx), %edx` to do a zero-extending load of a byte into a 32-bit register?  `(%ebx)` makes it a memory operand.  You also don't increment your pointer anywhere, just some other unrelated counter in `%ecx`.

Comment: Wait a minute, I just read the text.  You should be appending bytes to a buffer in memory, not `add`ing their integer value.  This is assembly language, `add` is integer addition not string concatenation like `"foo" + "bar"`.  *use a debugger* to single-step your code and watch registers + memory change.  And/or write some code in C and look at compiler output (from `gcc -Og` for example).

Comment: I see, thank you for the help! Could you tell me how I could append the bytes? I'm very new at this, and this language is nothing like the high-level ones I know from before

Comment: If you know C, most C statements map directly to asm.  e.g. `*dst = tmp; dst++` is `mov %dl, (%edi)` / `inc %edi`.